# How to extract date and time from Date Time Picker?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm working in a WinForm and have two Date Time Pickers: One that displays a short date and one that displays time. In my SQL DB, I have a DateTime field that I would like to populate using the two values of my DTPs put together.

This is what I have currently: (that isn't working)

```
myDateTimeField = Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_date.Text + dtp_time.Text);
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` `Add` method on the first `DateTimePicker`'s `Date` property, passing the `Timespan` returned by the second `DateTimePicker`'s `TimeOfDay` property.

```
DateTime myDateTimeField = dtp_date.Value.Date.Add(dtp_time.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Since the operator `+` has an overload where the left argument is a `DateTime` and the right one is a `TimeSpan`, this can also be written `dtp_date.Value.Date + dtp_time.Value.TimeOfDay`.

Comment: Good to know for the future. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the `Text` properties together try adding the values together:

```
var date = dtp_date.Value;
var time = dtp_time.Value.TimeOfDay;
myDateTimeField = date.Add(time);
```

Comment: Then I get this error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Just got this: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Add(System.TimeSpan)' has some invalid arguments, and Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Comment: Sorry - updated again. I am using an online compiler as I don't have access to VS on this machine and using `var`s seems to work.